# I am trying to loop through my data in text file and append it to list view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop

My textfile looks like this. Each value is on new row and I want to loop through this and show it into my listview.
I want to loop through 7 lines for one listview row

```
husnain
zahid
john
UET society
lahore
22
Thursday April 14 2022
00000000
uzair
ejaz
doe
nasheman iqbal phase 2
 lahore
27
2022 ,اپریل 16
000000
```

and I am using this loop to loop through files and save show it into my listview

```
 private void LoadDataToListview()
    {
        var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\SCD_Project\Theory Assignments\A2\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\addressBook.txt");
        lineval = fileLines.Length;
        
        
        for (int i = 1; i < 16; i += 8)
        {
            S3_manageAddress_listview.Items.Add(
                 new ListViewItem(new[]
                 {
                        fileLines[i],
                        fileLines[i + 1],
                        fileLines[i + 2],
                        fileLines[i + 3],
                        fileLines[i + 4],
                        fileLines[i + 5],
                        fileLines[i + 6],
                        fileLines[i + 7],
     }));          
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in C# are zero based, so you need to start your iteration at 0 and not 1.

```
private void LoadDataToListview()
{
    var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\SCD_Project\Theory Assignments\A2\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\addressBook.txt");
    var groupSize = 8;
    //lineval = fileLines.Length;
   
    // start iterating at 0
    for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.Length; i += groupSize)
    {
        S3_manageAddress_listview.Items.Add(
            new ListViewItem(new[]
            {
                fileLines[i],
                fileLines[i + 1],
                fileLines[i + 2],
                fileLines[i + 3],
                fileLines[i + 4],
                fileLines[i + 5],
                fileLines[i + 6],
                fileLines[i + 7],
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: worked for me
Can you explain me what was wrong with my loop

Comment: The issue was that you started your iteration at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: right Iguess thats why I was getting error of ARRAY INDEX OUT OF BOUND